# How to compile ffmpeg.c and its dependencies code in Eclipse?

Tags: ffmpeg

Since there is very limited number of ffmpeg examples, I want to know ffmpeg better through debugging ffmpeg process.

So with the downloaded ffmpeg code, I hope to only compile ffmpeg.c (has a main function) with its dependences in Eclipse.

But when I put the source in a project of Eclipse, it put out errors as:
‘F_NOCACHE’ undeclared (first use in this function) yuvcmp.c    /ffmpegTest/src/tools   line 63 C/C++ Problem

I failed to find information about F_NOCACHE.
Where and how to set its value?

Comment: There are a *lot* of dependencies of `ffmpeg.c`. As soon as you fix `F_NOCACHE`, you'll run into another one missing. And another. And so on, until you've practically gone through the entire FFmpeg source code. Just use the standard build process and use `gdb` or something to step through it.

Comment: Thanks. Once I have succeeded in compiling tesseract-ocr by compiling, errors, fixing errors, compiling, errors again, fixing, ... And finally it worked! So I thought I could do that to ffmpeg. I will follow your advice. I have a standard building. And I imported the ffmpeg executable into Eclipse, hoped I could debug it; but failed. I think I needed to do something when I build ffmpeg. Any idea? I am using Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse Juno. Thank you again.

Comment: No, sorry. Although it may not be so intuitive as Eclipse, have you tried debugging with `gdb`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I imported the ffmpeg executable into Eclipse, and tried to debug it. However,  there are no source code available for me to add break points.
There are two items under the project:
Binaries
ffmpeg - [x86_64/le]

Under ffmpeg - [x86_64/le]
there are several items:
speex_nb_mode:
speex_uwb_mode:
... (and several other items)

When I click "ffmpeg - [x86_64/le]", it is like:
ELF

Comment: Have you tried using `gdb` rather than Eclipse, though?

Comment: I am not familiar with gdb. I will try it. Thanks.